# how to name a subtab in service console in salesforce

Tags: servicecloud

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = testSetTabTitle;
    function testSetTabTitle(){
{
   sforce.console.setTabTitle('service');
}
//to set tab title on load
var pageLoad = window.onload;
window.onLoad = function(){
  if (testSetTabTitle){
    pageLoad();
}
testSetTabTitle();
}
</script>
```

written this code but this is not working .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a javascript issue.  With the block structure you have, you've placed all of your code into a function called by onLoad that then tries to modify onLoad, which wouldn't be called again.  Here is a simplified version.

```
//simplified - but see next code sample for improved version
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testSetTabTitle(){
        sforce.console.setTabTitle('service');
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        testSetTabTitle();
    }
</script>
```

Note that this will work in the simple case, but if another piece of code has set onload, you've just replaced that onload handler with your own.  You can save the original value and call it yourself, which I think you may have been trying to do; here's that version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testSetTabTitle(){
        sforce.console.setTabTitle('service');
    }

    // save the existing onload function, if any
    var orig_onload;
    if(window.onload) {
        orig_onload = window.onload;
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        // call the existing onload function, if any
        if (orig_onload) {
            orig_onload();
        }

        testSetTabTitle();
    }
</script>
```

Finally, make sure you include the console integration library in your vf page:

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/20.0/integration.js"/>
```